# ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Resource type is not included in the lis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rolify

I am new to rails.I am using rolify gem for adding user roles. 
I am getting this problem when I am trying to add a role from rails console. Does any have faced this problem ?

```
u = User.first
u.add_role(:admin).save!
```

error list ===

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Resource type is not included in the list.
```

Rolify migration file ============

```
class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table(:roles) do |t|
t.string :name
t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true
t.timestamps
end

create_table(:users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :role
end

add_index(:roles, :name)
add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
add_index(:users_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])

end
end`
```

I have followed the documentation for installing rolify from here ==
https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Comment: By any chance, have you run rake db:migration after starting rails console?

Comment: Can you past your model here?

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify
  rolify #:before_add => :add_default_role_to_user
  #resourcify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => :users_roles
  #after_save :add_default_role_to_user

  def role?(role)

  end

  def add_default_role_to_user
    current_user = User.find_by_id self.id
    #current_user.add_role :normal_user
  end
end

Comment: class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  validates :resource_type, :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types }

  scopify
end

Comment: here are the two models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that in version 3.5, it is not possible to create global role as happening in previous version. 
Actually whenever Role get created, it need resource_type, currently since you are creating global role which does not have any resource, its throwing errors. 
But if you create role on instance it will work. 
Consider you have some model named 'Post' as

```
Class Post
  resourcify 
end
On Rails console, create 
user = User.first
user.add_role(:admin, Post.first)
```

As i have given above scenerios, when i create role, it will get resource_type as 'Post'. But in your case, role does not getting resource_type. So if you want to create global role, then better would be remove ' validates :resource_type, :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types } ' from your 'role' model

Comment: Commenting the below line from model did the trick ' # validates :resource_type,
          :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
          :allow_nil => true'

Answer (score 0):

Version >= 3.5 has these issue, for time being use version rolify 3.4. I will fixed and send then pull request.

Comment: I have tried it. But it is creating this issue.
 Uncaught exception: undefined method `resource_types' for Rolify:Module.   this is the line where this is generated . === validates :resource_type, :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types }

Answer (score 0):

@Sazzad Please change the role model as given below:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true 

  scopify 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow `resource_type` to be `nil` on your `Role` Model.

For Rails 4, we had this in our `Role` model:

```
belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
validates :resource_type,
        :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
        :allow_nil => true
```

Starting in Rails 5, `belongs_to` association required by default, which is where `optional: true` comes in:

```
belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true, optional:true
validates :resource_type,
        :inclusion => { :in => Rolify.resource_types },
        :allow_nil => true
```